# Redis doesn't work after installing it on Mac using pecl

Tags: php, macos, redis

I ran this command on my MacOS Mojave:

```
pecl install redis
```

The result was success:

```
Build process completed successfully
Installing '/usr/local/Cellar/php@7.2/7.2.31/pecl/20170718/redis.so'
install ok: channel://pecl.php.net/redis-5.2.2
Extension redis enabled in php.ini
```

Then I restarted php by running:

```
brew services restart php@7.2
```

It is my understanding that Redis should now be available. However, I tried testing it in the command line using:

```
php -r "if (new Redis() == true){ echo \"\r\n OK \r\n\"; }"
```

And the result was:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Redis' not found in Command line code:1
```

I also have a Laravel application trying to use Redis and it, too, is throwing an error saying "Class Redis not found".

Anyone know what I can do to fix this?

Comment: `php -i | grep redis` shows anything interesting?

Comment: @matiit PWD => It finds phpredis in its download location: `/Users/jovan/Downloads/phpredis
$_SERVER['PWD'] => /Users/jovan/Downloads/phpredis
$_ENV['PWD'] => /Users/jovan/Downloads/phpredis`